# Play Framework configuration with java major.minor version

Tags: java, playframework

I want to check out the play framework. Therefore i have downloaded it (https://example.lightbend.com/v1/download/play-java - Version 2.5.x Java Seed) and ran sbt command in command prompt. I get this error, although Java 8 seems to be configured correctly. How do i fix this major.minor version problem. Here is my console output:

d:\code\play base\downlaoded\play-java>set $JAVA_HOME
$JAVA_HOME=c:\Java\java8sdk\

d:\code\play base\downlaoded\play-java>java -version
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)

d:\code\play base\downlaoded\play-java>sbt

d:\code\play base\downlaoded\play-java>.\sbt-dist\bin\sbt.bat
[info] Loading project definition from D:\code\play base\downlaoded\play-java\project
[info] Set current project to play-java-intro (in build file:/D:/code/play%20base/downlaoded/play-java/)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:559)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:559)
        at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:157)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$.com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load(SbtWeb.scala:573)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$globalSettings$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:143)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$globalSettings$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:143)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Function1.scala:55)
        at sbt.Project$.setProject(Project.scala:341)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:507)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:488)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:488)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
        at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
        at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
        at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)
        at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q

d:\code\play base\downlaoded\play-java>

Comment: Which version of sbt are you using?

Comment: Version 2.5.x added to the question

Comment: Add the contents of your `build.sbt` and `project\build.properties`

Comment: Not an expert on env variables, but you look like you are using windows, and the error certainly seems like a java version error (unless your build.sbt file is specifying an older java specifically). My start file has `set java_home=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77` in it.